# How to prove that $f(x)$ is a solution to a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In analysis I have to prove that the function $y = e^{\int_a^x f(t) dt}$ is a solution to the differential equation $y' = f(x) \cdot y$, however I simply cannot remeber how to.

It has been years since I have done this and I don't know where to start. Can you guide me in the right directon?

Thanks!

Comment: How about you differentiate the expression for $y$ (the one with the integral) ?

Comment: This is what I thought. So by finding y' and solving for f(x) I have the solution? Is it that simple?

Comment: Just try it and you'll see what the result is.

Comment: So we have $y' = e^{\int_a^x f(t) dt} \cdot f(t)$ and thus $y'/y = f(t) = f(x)$ and we are done?

Comment: The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus says $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(t)\,dt=f(x)$

Comment: So that is the last part I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y = e^{\int_a^x f(t) dt}$$
$$\ln y= {\int_a^x f(t) dt}$$
Differentiate both sides with respect to variable $x$. Apply chain rule on LHS and  Leibniz'rule on RHS:
$$\dfrac {d \ln y}{dx}=\dfrac {d}{dx} {\int_a^x f(t) dt}$$
$$\dfrac {d \ln y}{dy}\dfrac {dy}{dx}=\dfrac {d}{dx} {\int_a^x f(t) dt}$$
$$\dfrac {1}{y}\dfrac {dy}{dx}=\dfrac {d}{dx} {\int_a^x f(t) dt}$$
$$\dfrac {y'}{y}=\dfrac {d}{dx} {\int_a^x f(t) dt}$$
$$\dfrac {y'}{y}=f(x) \implies y'=yf(x)$$

Comment: How do you get $\frac{y'}{y}$? For $(\ln(y))' = \frac{1}{y}$?

Comment: you differentiate both sides with respect to x not y

Comment: I addes some lines is it more clear now @MathiasNissen

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: yw Mathias @MathiasNissen ....

Comment: Hi again. What is the reason that we can use the Chain Rule when taking the derivative on the LHS? Is it because when you differentiate in regards to a variable which is not present it is the same as using the Chain Rule? Or how should I understand it? I am very familiar with the Chain Rule in general but it just seems odd to me that we can use it in this case when we do not have a composite functions. Do you mind explaining?

Comment: Yes that's it exactly. You differentiate with respect to $x$ a function of $y$ we use then the chain rule so that for $f(y)$ we have :$$ \dfrac {df(y)}{dx}=\dfrac{df(y)}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{dx}$$  @MathiasNissen The last fraction is just $y'$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure Mathias @MathiasNissen

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use Chain Rule and Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.